# Calculate TotalAmount from all Rows in Table

Tags: c#, .net, sql, razor, webmatrix

Can you please help me with this? I am trying to calculate the total of all the rows in my Price Table, but the values never add up, and now it doesn't seem to calculate anymore either.

I have the following:

```
@{
    decimal money = 0.00m;
    var prices = "SELECT Price, SUM(Price) FROM PriceTable GROUP BY Price";

            var database = Database.Open("MYDB");
            database.QuerySingle(prices);
            money = prices.AsDecimal();
}
```

And somewhere in my HTML I type:

```
@money // to display the totalAmount
```

Am I doing it right? I've searched for this, but surprisingly there seems to be not much info about this, I'm probably not using the right keywords though.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change

```
var prices = "SELECT Price, SUM(Price) FROM PriceTable GROUP BY Price";
```

to

```
var prices = "SELECT SUM(Price) FROM PriceTable";
```

IF all you want is the sum of all rows, the grouping is not required.

Also;

```
var result = database.QuerySingle(prices);
money = Convert.ToDecimal(result);
```

Comment: Than kyou @Chris, I did not have the GROUP BY at first, but I added it after getting sn error abour something something aggregate, something does not contain GROUP - so it just popped into my head, maybe it's asking for GROUP BY :P

Comment: @Chris thank you but it still doesn't display the total amount. It just says $0.

Comment: I am not sure why it is not displaying, jsut assumed it was the problem with the sql as per the title.

Comment: got it. You are actually attempting to convert the sql statement to a decimal. Change to your code to something like; var result = database.QuerySingle(prices); and then convert result to decimal.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you add the price itself too. You sum only the distinct prices, so for every price that is unique, the sum is the same as the price.

To be short: Remove the price and the group by. Just query sum(price) over the whole table.

Answer (score 1):

`{@money}` <-- isn't this the correct syntax? not "@money" only if I remember correctly...
and also the comments below with the query! =]

Comment: Nah, if it's just one thing you just put the @ infront, but if there's more than one thing you gotta have it inside a codeblock @{ ... } - As far as I can remember anyway

Comment: and if you try this:

money = Decimal.parse(prices);

Comment: If I try that it goes psycho: "Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
"

Comment: doesn't the query (C# part) brings you back a DataTable or some kind of that instead of a single number? I mean you could try this one too:

"SELECT SUM(Price) AS 'Price' FROM PriceTable"

and the code would be:

money = prices["Price"].AsDecimal();

Comment: Thats what I originally tried, but it always brought back incorrect calculations. And even though none of the values in the rows changed, each time I refreshed the page, the calculations were different