# Sum of a column in Webmatrix

Tags: razor, sql-server-ce, webmatrix

I have searched for too many hours. [Calculate TotalAmount from all Rows in Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514059/calculate-totalamount-from-all-rows-in-table) was as close as I could find but could not get it to work.

I have a table called "ServiceEntered" and I need the SUM of the column "Price" to be displayed on the page. I have tried to change the field type in the table too but with no success.

I am using this code:

```
decimal money = 0.00m; 
var prices = "SELECT SUM(Price) FROM ServiceEntered"; 
var db = Database.Open("OMD"); 
var result = db.QuerySingle(prices); 
money = Convert.ToDecimal(result);
```

and have `@money` in the page.

It give me this error: Unable to cast object of type 'WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Comment: What is the datatype for the column?

Comment: I have it set to float right now. It is for money but I have heard that can cause problems.

Comment: Have you tried changing it to decimal?

Comment: it does not give that option in mysql compact that is included with webmatrix

Comment: That's not MySQL. It's SQL Compact Edition. You should use numeric and set the precision and scale to 19 and 4.

Comment: even with that, the code I find from the other pages do not work. Do you know the code that needs to be implemented?

Comment: What do you mean by "do not work"? Do you get errors? If so what? Or do you get an unexpected result?

Comment: I am using this code '    decimal money = 0.00m;
    var prices = "SELECT SUM(Price) FROM ServiceEntered";
    var db = Database.Open("OMD");
    var result = db.QuerySingle(prices);
    money = Convert.ToDecimal(result);' and have @money in the page. it give me this error: Unable to cast object of type 'WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL you are using is correct. However, the return type of the QuerySingle method is an object with properties generated dynamically from the database column(s) in your query. You have none - nor do you have any aliases for the expressions your SQL generates (the result of the SUM function).  In fact, since you are only retrieving a scalar value from the database, you should use [QueryValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database.queryvalue%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) instead. Try this:

```
var prices = "SELECT SUM(Price) FROM ServiceEntered";
var db = Database.Open("OMD");
var result = db.QueryValue(prices);
```

And then in your page you can use:

```
@result
```

Comment: You my friend are amazing, this is the second time you have helped me. Thank you so much!